# How to pack a SFX file created with DotNetZip library without destroy the file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dotnetzip, winzip, sfx

I've created a self executable with **DotNetZip** library and now I will pack the exe.

I've tried it with **UPX**, **BoxedAPP**, **.NET Shrink** and **IlMerge**, all of them destroys the SFX file.

> Important:

The reason of why I'm trying to pack the SFX is because I will find a way to avoid the **WinZip**/ **WinRar**/ **7Zip** or another extract options when right-clicking in the SFX file

I will mean the options: "**Extract file to..**.", "**Extract file here...**", etc.

So for me is valid any answer explaining how to pack the **DotNetZip** SFX or an answer explaining how to avoid that options when creating an SFX with **DotNetZip**.

Thankyou for read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the packer (like BoxxedApp Packer), you can create an executable file, it will run without the "Extract file to...", "Extract file here...", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have you created *exe* file by DotNetZip?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same situation. I exactly want it as you describe, because the way I use now has some security leaks.

**1)** I have added the Winrar SFX auto extractor (exe) to my project as resource.

**2)** I write the exe to a 'secret' hidden directory in background, all confusingly named.

**3)** After writing is complete, run the SFX (exe) from that location.

**4)** Extractor places file (movie in my case) in readonly (temp) mode in a directory and then runs the file.

**5)** My app tries to delete the exe (will succeed when extraction is complete, otherwise the exe is still in use).

**6)** When people close the movie player, the temp movie will be deleted immediately.

The difference with your approach is that I try to hide my files for now. If people know about that location and are able to retrieve the exe file before it gets removed, then they can just extract it instead of running it...
I hope we're able to run the exe from within resource, instead of writing it to pc thus possibly exposing the files to people.